# Como colocar classes dentro de vector e manipular variáveis com push_back?

Tags: c++, vector

Com certeza é algo simples, mas eu pesquisei e não entendi como fazer.

Se eu tenho por exemplo a seguinte classe, com duas variáveis:

```
class x {
public:
    int var1, var2;
};
```

Eu quero criar um `vector` desta classe, então eu declaro:

```
vector<x> teste;
```

Com array, seria fácil. Mas, esquecendo o uso de *setters*, apenas para facilitar aqui, eu quero atribuir valores às duas variáveis e em seguida fazer um `push_back` do vetor.

Como eu faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais direto sem alterar nada seria:

```
std::vector<x> teste;

x obj1; //criar o objeto
obj1.var1 = 10;
obj1.var2 = 20;
teste.push_back(obj1); //adicionar ao vetor com push_back

std::cout << teste[0].var1 << " " << teste[0].var2; //10 20
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/nkjTmB)

Mas se utilizar um construtor fica bem mais prático. Precisa primeiro de o incluir na sua classe:

```
class x {
public:
    int var1, var2;
    x(int v1, int v2):var1(v1), var2(v2) {} //construtor com inicializadores
};
```

Depois a criação do objeto fica:

```
x obj1(10,20); //agora cria utilizando o construtor
teste.push_back(obj1); //adicionar ao vetor com push_back
```

[Veja também este exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/Vbty59)

Se quiser pode fazer tudo numa só chamada que seria o mais prático, assim:

```
teste.push_back(x(10,20));
```

Assim consegue fazer várias adicões sem ter que estar constantemente a declarar variáveis auxiliares.

Como o amigo @MarioFeroldi comentou, pode utilizar também o método [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) em alternativa ao `push_back` com a diferença que constrói o elemento e adiciona, por isso faz as duas coisas ao mesmo tempo. A construção é feita com base no tipo do vetor.

```
teste.emplace_back(10, 20); //constroi o x com 10 e 20, e adiciona ao vector
```

Comment: É interessante mencionar [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), diminui ainda mais: `teste.emplace_back(10, 20)`.